# Kronig Penney Model Delta potential

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am finding it very hard to understand the implications of the equation obtained for the Kronig Penney Model from *Solid State Physics* by Kittel. The equation he obtained by using delta potential is

$$\frac{P}{Ka}\sin Ka+\cos Ka=\cos ka$$

where $k$ is a wave vector and

$$K=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}, \quad P=\frac{Q^2ab}{2}, \quad Q=\sqrt \frac{2m(U_0-E)}{\hbar^2} \, .$$
[image]

For me, the main problem has been how this equation leads to the origin of bands. Since the values of $\cos (ka)$ lies between -1 and +1, it gives the origin of allowed bands, but what about forbidden gaps or the band gaps.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but is really well meant advice: try another book along side Kittel. I found Kittel is extremely hard to understand. Ashcroft and Mermin may be better for you.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would define the symbols used in your equation :) I guess $a$ is the lattice spacing. What are $k$ and $K$? Are they the quasi-momentum and reciprocal lattice vectors? If so please state that in the question.

Comment: k is the wave vector while $K=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}$

Comment: Don't put it in a comment, put it in the question :)

Comment: You don't say what $P$ is. Help us help you.

Comment: What is $U_0$? Please understand that you have the book in front of you but we don't. You also didn't define $a$ and $b$. It's clear that $E$ is energy and $m$ is mass.

Comment: Now that you've posted an extremely similar question here (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153658/origin-of-band-gap) I would like to remind you that if an answer to a question is satisfactory it is customary to mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Hey, Roshan, it is customary on this site to accept an answer if it is satisfactory. You have not accepted an answer to this question. If there is something else you want to know please say so in a comment. Otherwise, it is best to accept an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider your equation

$$\frac{P}{Ka}\sin(Ka) + \cos(Ka) = \cos(ka) \, .$$

The right hand side can only ever attain values in the range $[-1,1]$.
Therefore, if there is an energy $E$ which causes the left hand side to take a value outside the range $[-1,1]$, then that $E$ can never be realized for any value of $k$.
In other words, that $E$ is forbidden and we say it sits in a "band gap".

We can see this graphically.
Here I plot the energy $E$ versus the value of the left hand side of the equation for the case

$$a=1, \quad b=10^{-4}, \quad U_0=10^4 \,.$$

The vertical blue line indicates the point at which the left hand side of the equation is $-1$.
Any points where we go to the left of that line are forbidden.
The red band indicates the range of $E$ over which the left hand side of the equation is outside the range $[-1,1]$.
As you can see, there is a band of values of $E$ where no possible $k$ can satisfy the equation.
This is a band gap.

[image]

Comment: What value did u use for K?I would like to plot the graph too

Comment: Also u have taken SI units right?

Comment: @Aladdin I did not choose any particular system of units.